# Jquery -Issue to get div content as html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get ALL the content of a div as html.
This is the script I'm using:

```
<script>
    $('.clickMe').click(function (event) {
        var content = $("div#myId").html();
        alert(content);
    });
</script>
```

It works when I'm having this html:

```
<div id="myId" class="clickMe">
    some content
</div>
```

The alert shows: "some content"

But it doesn't work when I do it like this below:

```
<div id="myId" class="clickMe">
    <p>some content</p>
    <br/>
    <p>some more content</p>
</div>
```

Then the alert never shows.
Note: I want it to alert ALL the html, so the output I want in my second alert example is:

```
"<p>some content</p><br/><p>some more content</p>"
```

EDIT:

I think I didn't wrote enough information about my real problem, sorry. The alert works!
But when I'm trying to use `var content = $("div#myId").html();` in a AJAX-post it fails, why is that?
When using my first example it works, but not when using the second

Here is my full code:

```
<script>
$('.clickMe').click(function (event) {
    var content = $("div#myId").html();
    alert(content);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/SaveContent',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            contentToUpdate: content
        },

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("works");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use $("div#myId").contents();

Comment: What is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/408/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - did the same thing and it works on my side =/

Comment: does alert support that? Have you tried putting it in console.log?

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: Its better to encode the html before posting.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi How do I do that?

Comment: @user3228992 contentToUpdate: escape(content)

Answer (score 2):

I think all the answer provided should be correct.
Have you make sure that u have different id on each div.

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,''));
});
```

if you trying to get the content of clicked content u may want to use 'this' instead of get the content by the id.

see on jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/71krrfqf/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("div#myId").html()` try `$("div#myId").text()`

OR (Wrap your jquery code inside `document.ready()` as shown below)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickMe').click(function (event) {
        var content = $("div#myId").html();
        alert(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: "Note: I want it to alert ALL the html".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show html than use

```
    var content = $("div#myId").html();
    alert(content); // content not cont
```

NOTE : use DOM ready function

```
$(function(){
    $('.clickMe').click(function (event) {
        var content = $("div#myId").html();
        alert(content);
    });
})
```

Comment: just a typo when posting my question, sorry =) Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use below script to get content **without linebreaks**.

```
$('.clickMe').click(function (event) {
    var content = $("div#myId").html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    alert(content);
});
```

Hope this helps.